# @font-face - IE9 -- Font not loading

Tags: css, fonts, weblogic, font-face

For some reason, on our Weblogic test server, IE9 will not render @font-face fonts correctly.  They load fine on our local development environment, but when we deploy to test, Font Awesome and TinyMCE4's icon fonts do not load.

I've narrowed down the issue to the fact that IE9 seems to be loading the woff & ttf fonts AFTER the eot font (see SS below), but cannot figure out why it works properly in our dev environment, but not on the test server:

[image]

As you can see, it is loading the eot properly, but for some reason it continues on, and still loads the woff & ttf.  This does not happen in our dev environment (only the EOT is loaded).  I have set the mime types in the web.xml as follows:

```
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>eot</extension>
    <mime-type>application/vnd.ms-fontobject</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>ttf</extension>
    <mime-type>application/x-font-ttf</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>woff</extension>
    <mime-type>application/x-font-woff</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>otf</extension>
    <mime-type>font/opentype</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

and the @font-face declaration looks correct:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    src: url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=3.0.1');
    src: url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=3.0.1')format('embedded-opentype'), url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=3.0.1')format('woff'), url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=3.0.1')format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal
}
```

I have searched high and low for other IE9 @font-face issues (there are plenty of others with IE9 font-face issues), but none of the solutions seem to work on our end.  I'm guessing it has something to do with the serving of the files from our server.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps the `?v=3.0.1` part is breaking something in IE9?

Comment: I can't see that being the issue, given that all other sites using font awesome are doing the same thing, and work fine on IE9 (including our dev environment).  I have a feeling it's something specific to the way the files are being served from our server.

Comment: Additionally, TinyMCE4's icomoon pack doesn't have a ?xxx, and they aren't rendering either.

Comment: Maybe temporarily put the fonts on a known working server and see what the difference is. Or use the CDN version `<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
`

Comment: Alex, yeah, I'm giving that a try now... Thanks ...  I don't think our QA people will allow CDN-served content as a permanent solution, but to see if it resolves the issue, will give it a try and go from there.

Comment: Could it be an "access-control-allow-origin *" problem?  I've only noticed this in FF so far, but might be worth looking into those permissions, if you load the font from another domain that is.

Comment: Was this ever resolved? I notice that the size of the responses for ttf and woff aren't big enough to contain the actual content.  I'm experiencing the same thing in one user's IE10.

Comment: We "kinda" fixed it.  Our DB unit changed the weblogic server deployment mode setting from "stage" to "nostage".  This seemed to resolve the issue.  However, other applications were on "stage" mode and did not have the icon issue.